# Values all null in column after I put query in S3

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

Recently, I put my datamart queries in s3 as it's too long to be queried directly. After that, some random columns in the tables will have all values become null. I re-run the queries manually and some will be ok and then some other columns have all values become null.

I am using Redshift for my datamart and the AWS pipeline for running hourly schedules.

Comment: Can you add more details? What is datamart? Code snippets? Table schema?

Comment: Add your COPY command as well.